# How to obtain the geometry of a subwidget in QMainWindow

Tags: qt

I want to get the actual geometry of a promoted widget in the QMainWindow. Here below is a screenshot of the main window design.

[image]

The `renderImage` is a promoted widget using a defined `renderImage` class, which is used for image painting. Now I want to get the actual position of the widget in the `QMainWindow` in `renderimage.cpp`, in order for painting at that region where the widget is located.

Is there some method for get this geometry information. I know in the `mainwindow.cpp`, such geometry information can be accessed:

```
QRect rect = ui->renderImage->geometry()
```

But then how to inform `renderImage.cpp` of the result? Thanks!

Comment: use  `this->geometry()` inside of renderImage.cpp

Comment: @eyllanesc: nice neat!!

Comment: @eyllanesc: I have a follow-up question for you. I find that when I use painter.drawRect(QRect(renderImgRect.x(),renderImgRect.y(),renderImgRect.width(),renderImgRect.height())) to draw a rectangle on the subwiget of the same size as the subwidget, only two (upper and left) sides are displayed. I wonder if the drawing starting coordinate is relative to the subwidget or main widget? Thanks!

Comment: `geometry()` is relative to the parent widget, that you should not use to paint inside the widget, instead use `rect()`.